# Programming in C: Making a substring function

Tags: c

I'm doing a problem from Programming in C that requires me to make a program that takes a word, and a start position as well as number of words to take, and puts it into a result array. I've seen some solutions online, but they all use POINTERS, which I can't use, because we're not in that section yet.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char substring (char source[], int start, int count, char result[])
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; (i < count) && (source[start + i] != '\0'); ++i)
  {
    result[i] = source[start + i];
  }

  result[i + 1] = '\0';

  return result;
}

int main (void)
{
  char substring (char source[], int start, int count, char result[]);
  char source[81];
  char result[81];
  int start, count;

  printf ("Enter the word you want to check!\n");
  printf ("And the start position as well as the number of words to count!\n");
  scanf ("%s %i %i", &source[81], &start, &count);

  printf ("Your result is: %s\n", substring(source, start, count, result));
}
```

I keep on getting errors when compiling and when I fix them I don't get a result. Thanks.

Comment: Does this code compile with or without errors?  If with errors (or warnings), what are they?  At this stage in your career, if the compiler warns, it means there's a problem you need to fix.

Comment: Note that `&source[81]` is a major problem; you're passing beyond the end of your array `char source[81];` to `scanf()`.  You need either `&source[0]` or just `source` there instead.

Comment: Your descriptions says "a start position as well as number of words to take, and puts it into a result array"; your code seems to be counting characters, not words.  Which did you mean really?

Comment: Technically you use pointers too! When you declare a function argument like e.g. `char source[]` the compiler treats it as `char *source`. So in the `substring` function you don't have arrays, you have *pointers*.

Comment: 1) remove the prototype from the function `main()` for function: `substring()`  2) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  3) when calling `scanf()` and using the `%s` format specifier, always include a 'max characters' modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer, to avoid any buffer overflow.  Note: a buffer overflow is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers, like 81.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis and make the code much harder to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names and using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: if `start` and `count` are both 0 then this line: `result[i + 1] = '\0';` allows 1 character into the array `result[]`, not what you want.    Note: in C, array offsets start with 0, not 1, and end at 'number of characters in array-1'

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pendantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
scanf ("%s %i %i", &source[81], &start, &count)
```

to

```
scanf ("%s %i %i", source, &start, &count)
```

Also in the function you are returning a `char` and trying to print it with a `%s`. You should return a `char*` for that. So, the function becomes,

```
char* substring (char source[], int start, int count, char result[])
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; (i < count) && (source[start + i] != '\0'); ++i)
  {
    result[i] = source[start + i];
  }

  result[i + 1] = '\0';

  return result;
}
```

Comment: the proposed 'fix' for the call to `scanf()` still allows the user to overrun the input field, so this answer leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: @user3629249 While I agree that scanf has some flaws, this post is not the place to point them out, The answer solved the issues faced by OP and was the first one to point out both issues.

Comment: The answer misleads the OP because it does not properly present how to handle a char array input from the user.  It is not the `scanf()` function that is flawed, it is the proposed answer that is flawed.   Simplest fix, edit the call to `scanf()` to properly input a char array.

Comment: @user3629249 Can you tell me what would be your solution?

Comment: the correction to the `scanf()` function would be: `scanf ("%80s %i %i", source, &start, &count)`  Of course, using 'magic' numbers in the body of the code is never a good idea. suggest: ... #define MAX_CHAR_LEN (80) ... char source[ MAX_CHAR_LEN+1]; .... scanf ("%" MAX_CHAR_LEN "s %i %i", source, &start, &count)`

Comment: 1) If you are going down that road, it should be `%79s` and set `source[79] = '\0'`. 2) This approach will not work if you enter a string of 90 characters. The scanf `%79s` will read 79 characters and the remaining 11 will remain in the buffer. and will cause errors in the reading of `start` and `count`. 3) I reiterate, reading input from `scanf` in a safe manner for all possible situations is a different problem, which need not be addressed here.

Comment: the OP declared the array to be 81 characters.  So did I.  so the 'max characters' modifier can be 80, which is what I used.    However, the code should be checking the returned value from `scanf()` to assure (in this case) it is 3.  Anything else, means an error occurred.  At which time the code should drain stdin, output some error message, and start over.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass `&source[81]` to the `scanf` function you pass a pointer to the 82:nd character in the array, which is out of bounds leading to *undefined behavior*.

You should pass a pointer to the *first* character in the array: `&source[0]`.

Also note that `&source[0]` is equal to plain `source` since arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element.

Answer (score 1):

Do not declare/prototype the function inside `main`:

```
int main (void)
{
    char substring (char source[], int start, int count, char result[]);
    ...
```

Instead:

```
char substring (char [], int, int, char []);

char substring (char source[], int start, int count, char result[])
{
   ...
```

As stated by @Someprogrammerdude, you are passing the address of the last element of the array: `&source[81]` to `scanf`, you need to pass the address of the first element: `&source[0]` (or simply `source`), another problem is that you are returning a plain `char` where you want to return a string, change to

```
char *substring (char source[], int start, int count, char result[])
```

Comment: There is a prototype there.  It isn't necessary to put it inside `main()` as well, but it is technically legal, and it isn't 'old C style' (in the normal sense of the term).  You're right, too, that the function should return a `char *`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Where is the prototype?

Comment: The function is defined using prototype notation; there is also a prototype in `main()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes I mean do not declare the prototype inside main, edited